# Многопоточность java передача данных между потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность

Написал простую программу, которая одновременно запускает 5 потоков усыпляет их на разное время и потом сообщеает об их пробуждении. После этого необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователю программа задала вопрос из главного потока о том, не хочет ли пользователь повторить эксперимент.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

    public class Test{

    static long max = 0;

    static int k = 0;

    private static final int count = 5;

    public static CountDownLatch START = new CountDownLatch(count);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<NewThread> list = new ArrayList<NewThread>();


        long t = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            t = (long) (Math.random()*1000);
            list.add(new NewThread(t));
            max = (max <= t) ? (max = t) : (max = max);
            START.countDown();

        }

        boolean isNext = getPovtor();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            list.get(i).setNext(isNext);
            list.get(i).resume();
        }
    }

    private static boolean getPovtor(){
        try {
            START.await();
            Thread.sleep(max);
            System.out.println("Хотите протестировать еще раз?");
            System.out.println("Для продолжения введите \"Да\"");
            System.out.println("Для окончания введите любое другое сообщения");
            START = new CountDownLatch(5);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("res " + s);
            return s.equals("Да");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static class NewThread extends Thread{

        long time;
        Thread t;

        boolean isNext;

        NewThread(long time){
            this.time = time;
            this.t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        private void setTime(long time) {
            this.time = time;
            START.countDown();
        }

        private void setNext(boolean isNext){
            this.isNext = isNext;
        }

        public void run(){
            try {
                START.await();
                startRace();
                t.suspend();

                setNext(getPovtor());

                while(isNext) {
                    setTime(((long) Math.random()*1000));
                    START.await();
                    startRace();
                        setNext(getPovtor());
                }

                setTime(((long) Math.random()));
                START.await();
                startRace();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void startRace(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println("Поток " + t.getName() + " спал \"" + time + "\" мс");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Так как пересоздавать потоки нельзя, то необходимо сделать так, чтобы метод run не завершался до тех пор, пока не будет получен отрицательный ответ от пользователя. В связи с этим возникает вопрос, как передать управление главному потоку, чтобы провести опрос пользователя в нем?
воспользовавшись методами resume и suspend смог сделать опрос в главном потоке, однако далее программа выполнять метод run не стала. не пойму в чем проблема?

Comment: откуда эта задача? курсы какие-то? уже не первый раз этот вопрос вижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно так (этот код, конечно, можно улучшить).

```
public class ThreadsExperiment {

    private final int threadsCount;
    private final int maxPauseMs;

    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;

    public ThreadsExperiment (int threadsCount, int maxPauseMs){
        this.threadsCount = threadsCount;
        this.maxPauseMs = maxPauseMs;
        barrier = new CyclicBarrier(threadsCount + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
            new TimerThread().start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadsExperiment experiment = new ThreadsExperiment(5, 5000);

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Хотите протестировать потоки?");
            System.out.println("Для продолжения введите \"y\"");
            System.out.println("Для окончания введите любое другое сообщения");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                experiment.go();
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void go(){
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(maxPauseMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    class TimerThread extends Thread{

        TimerThread(){
            super();
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            while(true){
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                doit();
            }
        }

        void doit(){

            Long time1 = (new Date()).getTime();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(maxPauseMs));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Long time2 = (new Date()).getTime();

            System.out.println("Поток " + this.getName() + " спал \"" + (time2 - time1) + "\" мс");
        }
    }

}
```